# $\int \left| f_n \right|< M$ then $\left| f_n(x) \right|\leq g(x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Is it true that if for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ : $\int_I  \left| f_n(x) \right| \,\mathrm{d}x < M$, where $M \in \mathbb{R}$, then there exists an integrable function $g$ (in the Riemann sens) such that for all : $n$ : $\left| f_n(x) \right| \leq g(x)$ ?

I think there is a link with the dominated convergence theorem, but I am unable to find a counterexample.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

Think about a series of step functions that have shrinking width and increasing height.

Comment: Ok so there is a counterexample. Maybe : $n\mathbb{1}_{[0, 1/n]}$ ?

Comment: Yep. That's the prototypical example!

Comment: OK, thank you, but are you shure that :$ \int_I \mid n\mathbb{1}_{[0, 1/n]} \mid < M, \forall n $ ?

Comment: because we have : $\int_I n\mathbb{1}_{[0, 1/n]} dx = n\mathbb{1}_{[0, 1/n]} \cdot \int_I 1 dx$, so we don't have the inequality ?

Comment: We do, actually! What is the integral of $1$ over the interval $[0,1/n]$?

Comment: It's $1/n$ but here $I$ is fixed. We defined the set of function : $f_n : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \forall x \in I f_n(x) = n\mathbb{1}_{[0, 1/n]}$

Comment: Yes. $I$ is fixed, BUT if you integrate a step function over an interval, it chops that interval down!

Comment: Think of it this way, you're integrating a function that is $1$ from $[0,1/n]$ and $0$ from $[1/n]$ to $1$ (or whatever endpoint you want). What's the integral of that function?

Comment: Ok I got it ! Thank you !